# Isolate/sandbox part (i.e. plugin) of app

Tags: ios, objective-c, plugins, sandbox, javascriptcore

I'm currently testing functionality that allows the user of an application to create scripts/plugins - so to speak - within the app (using JavaScriptCore). These plugins allow them, for example, to make calls on objects and present view controllers. The issue lies in the fact that the user may make a mistake which results in an exception being raised, for example if they send a message that an object does not respond to or try to present an already active view controller.

So far I've been looking into catching all exceptions within my app using `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` and my thought was to isolate the execution of the script/plugin in a separate thread then exit that thread using `[NSThread exit]` when an exception occurs, thus preventing a full crash of the app. The issues with that were two-fold, firstly exiting a thread early causes memory to be leaked of all objects allocated and not released up to that point; and secondly, anything UI related cannot be handled on a separate thread.

Along with the need to prevent crashes due to the script/plugin, it would also be necessary to be able to terminate the script (this likely could be a whole separate question in itself) on demand, for example a stop button. This would terminate any set up timers for example and I believe having the plugin run on a separate thread would also handle this as they'd be within a separate run loop.

Admittedly this is a far from ideal situation and if this was on OS X then my first thought would be to spawn a sandboxed sub-process and make use of XPC. However, one is unfortunately not afforded that luxury on iOS.

Any ideas/suggestions on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test your script in "safe" environment you can subclass NSOperation class and perform your script in custom **main** function. In your NSOperation subclass you need to implement **start** method and call **main** from **@try @catch** block

```
-(void)start {
    @try {
       [self main];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
       NSLog(@"Exception was raised");
    }
}

-(void)main {
   // Perform script here
}
```

Eventually you need to add this operation to the main operation queue

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:[MyScriptOperation new]];
```

So your script will be running on the main thread and you will be able to perform UI actions.

Also with additional configuration you will be able to manually run and cancel this operation. You can find more details about NSOperation subclassing and implementation details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1).

Comment: Using a try-catch block with JSContext's (JavaScriptCore) `evaluateScript:` doesn't appear to catch exceptions caused as a result of a call in the script. e.g. if an exported method called from the JS throws an exception

Comment: Have you seen this [article](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/javascriptcore-example/)? There is a paragraph called "Catch me if you can" which describe how to catch JS exception. Maybe it will help to solve your problem.

Comment: I have indeed but unfortunately it's no JS exceptions I'm having issue catching, rather it's Obj-C exceptions thrown as a result of a call from Javascript. If it wasn't for my specific situation in using JavaScriptCore then I believe your answer would suit well.

Comment: Bounty awarded as this seems to be the best all round answer though unfortunately doesn't work in my specific situation involving JavaScriptCore.

Comment: Thanks. Hope you will find solution for your specific problem soon.